# How do you calculate the sum based on certain numbers in the dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have variables like this

```
a = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 1, 2, 3, 2], [2, 2, 3, 3, 2], [1, 2, 3, 2, 3]]))

b = np.array([0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.6, 0.2])
```

Display `a`

```
   0    1      2      3      4                                         
0  1    1      2      3      2                    
1  2    2      3      3      2
2  1    2      3      2      3
```

Display `b`

```
[0.1    0.3    0.5    0.6    0.2]
```

The result I want is the sum of the values in `b` based on the values of `a` where the indices of `a` serve as the indices for the values in `b` .

The **final result** that I want is like this.

```
 0.4   0.7  0.6
   0   0.5  0.11                     
 0.1   0.9  0.7
```

**How to obtain the first row in detail**

```
 0.4   0.7  0.6
```

- so `0.4` is obtained from `0.1 + 0.3`, based on the number 1 in the first row of `a`, i.e. since the indices are `0` and `1`, we add `b[0]` and `b[1]`
- `0.7` is obtained from `0.5 + 0.2`, based on the number 2 where the indices are `2` and `4`, so we added `b[2] + b[4]`
- `0.6` based on the number 3 which is just `b[3]` because the index is `3`

Comment: can you explain the logic more please? thank you , how do you get the first row for example

Comment: for example, the value 0.4 in the first row is obtained from `b`" 0.1 + 0.3 "..
based on the value 1 which is in the `a` variable

the value 1 appears twice, namely indexs 0 and 1 ..
so the index 0 and 1 on the `b` variable are 0.1 and 0.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way you can do it, it is not optimized, yet I think it follows your logic in a clear way:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=range(1, a.max().max()+1))
for i,r in a.iterrows():
    for c in list(df):
        df.loc[i,c] = np.sum((b[r[r==c].index.values]))

df 
     1    2    3
0  0.4  0.7  0.6
1    0  0.6  1.1
2  0.1  0.9  0.7
```

Comment: thank you for helping me :)
I want to ask again ...
how to change the column length automatically?
column length will automatically change following the length of variables `a `and `b` ...

so if I want to change the length of the variables `a` and `b` , I don't need to change the syntax  `(columns = [1,2,3,4])`

Comment: I get an error when using multiple rows on the `a` variable.. how to fix it??

`df.loc[i, c] = np.sum((b[r[r == c].index.values]))
IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type`

Answer (score 6):

You can create one-hot encoded matrices to use in a dot product:

```
from pandas.api.types import CategoricalDtype
n = a.max().max()
cat = CategoricalDtype(categories=np.arange(1, n + 1))
dummies = pd.get_dummies(a.T.astype(cat))
b.dot(dummies).reshape(n, n)
```

yields

```
array([[0.4, 0.7, 0.6],
       [0. , 0.6, 1.1],
       [0.1, 0.9, 0.7]])
```

Comment: I want to ask again ... how to change the categories length automatically? categories length will automatically change following the length of variables a and b ... so if I want to change the length of the variables a and b , I don't need to change the syntax

Comment: Nice! This is the most pythonic solution!

Comment: @riokuroky You can define a constant `n = a.max().max()` and change `categories = [1, 2, 3]` to `categories = np.arange(1, n +1)` and reshape part to `reshape(n, n)` if you have values going from 1..n If you have arbitrary values you may need to use pd.unique to get a list of the categories.

Comment: @ayhan I don't know what I have to do, can you edit the code?

Comment: @ayhan I want to ask again ... after getting that value ...
I look for the highest value of each row with Sintax
`test = b.dot (dummies). threshold (n, n)`
`np.argmax (test, axis = 1) + 1`
the result is `[2 3 2]`
what if I want to add a row to the `b` variable ..?
the result I want is [[2 3 2] [...] [...]] <<< depending on the number of lines